# How can I follow my own question (so I get notice of comments)?

Tags: support, email, follow-posts

I would like to get an email when someone has posted a comment or solution to a question that I have asked.  I have seen a couple of questions/discussions about this, and they all mention a "Follow" button or Star button.  I can not find either of these on my questions.  The buttons that I see are: Share Edit Delete Flag; no Follow.  If I look at some else's question, then I see Follow in place of Delete.

Is there a way for me to receive an email notice when something new has been posted to one of my questions?  I am talking about receiving an email, so I know to login and see what comments/answers have been posted.

Comment: I thought you would always receive a message when it's added to one of your posts. (Which might be proven by this comment)

Comment: Not sure about individual comments, but if you go to settings -> edit email settings, you can turn on inbox emails every three hours. Might not be frequent enough though

Comment: It was nice when the old mobile app had push notifications for comments / edits / answers.

Comment: When you ask the question, there's a checkbox to sign up for notifications before clicking "Post"

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  I haven't seen that.  I will see if I can find it when I have occasion to ask another question.

Comment: I do find it a bit weird that you don't have a follow button. That's a rather strange thing to explicitly not allow the question author to use on their own question, Surely it's useful to toggle these notifications on and off as desired.

Comment: @KevinB There's a checkbox for "Answer your own question," but I don't see one that lets you sign up for notifications.

Comment: It’s at the very bottom of the review stage

Comment: @KevinB I don't want to say that you're wrong, but the only checkbox I see in the review stage is labelled "Answer your own question". Perhaps the feature has been removed since you last looked, or maybe there's a bug that prevents it from showing up in some browsers.

Comment: Are you using the new editor? I only tested with the old. It’s directly above the post your question button, with missing top margin

Comment: The system is designed such that you **always** get notifications of new answers added to your questions and new comments placed on your posts (unless they're deleted prior to you looking at the notification). If you're not getting these in your Stack Exchange network-wide inbox, then Something Is Wrong™. In fact, you can't turn such notifications off (i.e. there's no way to *not* get such notifications for your posts; being able to turn those off has been requested multiple times). If you are getting such inbox notifications, but not an email, then verify your email preferences and settings.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate if the issue is that you're not getting inbox notifications (which show up as a badge on the inbox looking icon in the topbar) or if it's that you are getting those, but not getting those forwarded as email.

Comment: Mayken - I see badge notifications (when logged in, obviously).  I edited the post to emphasize that I am talking about receiving email.  Strangely, when I fired up my computer/email this morning, I did have emails regarding your comments (and a couple of others).  This is the first time this has happened.  Perhaps it has something to do with the migration that someone did to this question?

Comment: You can't follow your own posts because "follow" means "get notified like you own the post". It would be completely redundant.

Comment: I kinda like that I actively have to visit SE sites in order to view my new notifications. It makes it less stressful, and less invasive. A discussion doesn’t need a fast reply anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In summary:

1. A question author cannot follow their own question, and will automatically receive notifications, inside Stack Overflow, of comments on the question.
2. The question author will also receive an email regarding comments that are posted.

   However, the notices are accumulated over a period of time and sent in a single email, rather than one real-time email when each comment is posted.  The accumulation period is selected in the user's preferences.  The available accumulation periods are quite long, with the shortest being 3 hours.

   You only get an email alert when there are *unread* notices in your inbox.

Answer (score -8):

> I have seen a couple of questions/discussions about this, and they all mention a "Follow" button or Star button.

There used to be a star-shaped button for marking questions that you particularly liked. It seems to have morphed into the bookmark button that you'll find just below the down-vote button:

[image]

The bookmark button lets you "save" a question so that it's easy to find later. As far as I know, it doesn't set up any notifications, but it does at least make it easier to get back to the question to check for updates. Of course, you do get notifications in SO about comments added to questions or answers that you've written.

Comment: I was expecting functionality that every other forum I have used provides - where you receive an email whenever anyone posts a comment, etc.; you don't have to log in and check.  I am getting the feeling that, for whatever reason, Stack Overflow just doesn't have this capability - which seems very odd to me.

Comment: @russ an email for every comment?! your inbox would be flooded with emails then which i don't think you'll find pleasant

Comment: @machine_1 eh, it's a valid request. On SO comments often come in batches, and notification emails from SO do too, with one email per batch.

Comment: When one is trying to solve a problem, getting comments (i.e. potential solutions) ASAP is exactly what one wants.  Flooded? I hardly consider a handful of emails to be a flood.  Regardless, a simple button to toggle this off/on would halt the deluge if one should occur.

Comment: @russ I think it's a legit feature request, just not something that exists today in the form that you want on SO. I'm not sure why this picked up so many downvotes -- I hope that someone will correct me if something I've said here is incorrect.

Comment: Caleb, I don't understand the significance of the up/down vote; or how it might reflect on you; seems a rather odd thing.  Even my question received down votes, whatever that means.  Anyway, thanks for taking the time to weigh in.

Comment: @russ On the main site, you build reputation by asking or answering questions, and people vote up if they're good (thoughtful, clear, researched, etc.) or down if they're bad (little effort, no research). More reputation means more community trust, and more privileges on the site. On meta it's a little different: you don't have separate reputation, and up/down votes tend to signify agreement or disagreement. I don't care about the downvotes here, but I'd like to know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Russ, you've run into the "Stackoverflow is not a forum" problem. It's not a forum. It's a database of high-quality questions and answers, and the site behaviour was chosen and implemented to meet the site's purpose. That doesn't mean that it couldn't do with a couple forum-like behaviours; just that they generally aren't there because they don't make for a better database.

Comment: As Caleb said, [Voting is different on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: user4581301 - Ah, thanks for the explanation/clarification.  I guess I can see how a question about how to use the site/database isn't consider high-quality, but.... it still seems important that someone posing a question should know if there was a response - so they can expand/clarify the question and/or accept an answer.

Comment: @russ " I don't understand the significance of the up/down vote" - good that you acknowledge it, now *don't ignore it*. It is a clear signal you do not understand Stack Overflow because voting is a fundamental aspect of it. Doing nothing with that realization is going to end up causing problems for you sooner or later. Find the documentation. Read it. Prevent yourself from ending up severely disliking the site.